# Camel CXF Component: Headers missing after service response

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, camel-cxf

My camel route is a CXF receiver & it needs to call another webService. I stored the request in header & requested second service. After getting response I am not able to retrieve the original request set in header.
My route looks like:

```
 <route customId="true" id="wsRoute">
    <from uri="cxf:bean:ServiceEndpoint"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="com.customer.requestcustomeremail.SendEmailRequest"/>
    <setHeader headerName="req">
        <simple>${body}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="bean:IDBReq"></to>
    <to uri="cxf:bean:idamServiceEndpoint"/>
    <setBody>
        <simple>
            ${header.req}
        </simple>
   </setBody>
   <to uri="bean:ServiceImpl?method=oper" />
```

**Error Message**: No body available of type:

> com.customer.requestcustomeremail.SendEmailRequest but has
>   value:
>   com.customer.requestcustomeremail.SendEmailRequest@1bcd32c6
>   of type: java.lang.String on: Message[]. Caused by: No type converter
>   available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type:
>   com.customer.requestcustomeremail.SendEmailRequest with value
>   com.customer.requestcustomeremail.SendEmailRequest@1bcd32c6.
>   Exchange[ID-SYNPS31625-50686-1504258200956-0-2]. Caused by:
>   [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type
>   converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the
>   required type:
>   com.customer.requestcustomeremail.SendEmailRequest with value
>   com.customer.requestcustomeremail.SendEmailRequest@1bcd32c6]

Can someone please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your route cannot convert your body to com.customer.requestcustomeremail.SendEmailRequest type.

Comment: You can try for test, not convert your body, and see if yuo will have the a similar error.